# PHP Script called multiple times whereas URL only called once

Tags: php, tar, php-ziparchive

I've got a script to backup a directory on a hosted webserver. The directory should be compressed about 1GB.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
include 'Archive/Tar.php'; 

$dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../dir_to_zip/'); 
$archivname = dirname(__FILE__)."/backup_".basename($dir).date('_Y-m-d_His').".tar.gz"; 

$archiv = new Archive_Tar($archivname, 'gz'); 
$archiv->createModify($dir, ""); 
echo 'done';
```

However, I call the script via Brwoser (Firefox) and CronJob of the hoster multiple archives are created:

| File | Size |
| --- | --- |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_143924.tar.gz` | 129MB |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_143954.tar.gz` | 130MB |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_144024.tar.gz` | 135MB |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_144054.tar.gz` | 139MB |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_144125.tar.gz` | 159MB |
| `backup_dir_to_zip_2023-04-01_144156.tar.gz` | 140MB |

Its very suspicios that the partial archives are created every 30 seconds. It seems like any "keep-alive"/"refresh" from the browser that starts the script again and again.

I am also happy to hear about alternatives to zip a large file ( I know, very common problem). I have tried `ZipArchive`, but getting an `ZipArchive::ER_MULTIDISK` Exception while using the `addFile`-Method or an memory-overflow using the `addFromString`-method.

Comment: Jobs like that are not meant for the web. Let a cronjob do the backup....

Comment: is not suspicious you are creating a filename which is unique every second and there are no checks on an existing backup, each request will just make a new backup

Comment: @HonkderHase it is for a cronjob.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes thats right. But I am only doing ONE request. An Archive should be abou 1GB, not 150MB.

Comment: why do you think it should be 1GB?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone previous and working archives of the same directory were about 1GB